# Using an ASP.NET SiteMap for a Page with multiple paths

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a certain page (we'll call it MyPage) that can be accessed from three different pages. In the Web.sitemap file, I tried to stuff the XML for this page under the three separate nodes like this:

< Page 1 >
    < MyPage / >
    ...
< /Page 1 >
< Page 2 >
    < MyPage / >
    ...
< /Page 2 >
< Page 3 >
    < MyPage / >
    ...
< /Page 3 >

In doing so I received the following error:

Multiple nodes with the same URL 'Default.aspx' were found. 
XmlSiteMapProvider requires that sitemap nodes have unique URLs.

I read online that the SiteMapNodes are stored as a dictionary internally which explains why I can't use the same URL.  In any case, I'm just looking for alternate ways to go about solving this problem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I need the page to include the sitemap because I'm saving context from each of the three previous pages. That way the user can click the previous page in the sitemap, and it will load the data I stored (i.e. load the data from their previous search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really the intended purpose of the Web.sitemap file.

From [MSDN Docs of the SiteMap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap(VS.80).aspx),

> Fundamentally, the SiteMap
>   is a container for a hierarchical
>   collection of SiteMapNode objects.
>   However, the SiteMap does not maintain
>   the relationships between the nodes;
>   rather, it delegates this to the site
>   map providers.

So, to paraphrase, the web.SiteMap only describes the *hierarchy* of the pages, and not the relationships *between* those pages.

However, if your intention is just to have the 'MyPage" linked from your other pages, then you don't need to have MyPage as child nodes of those other pages anyway.

Hope that helps clarify things a little.

Comment: I need the page to include the sitemap because I'm saving context from each of the three previous pages. That way the user can click the previous page in the sitemap, and it will load the data I stored (i.e. load the data from their previous search).

Answer (score 0):

I know you can have two different entries of ~/folder/index.aspx and ~/folder/ both point to the same place. A bit of a hack, yes, but maybe there's a way you can take this further?

- ~/folder/index.aspx
- ~/folder/
- ~/folder

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
<siteMapNode url="ListAll.aspx">
  <siteMapNode url ="Detail.aspx?node=all" />
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="ListMine.aspx">
  <siteMapNode url ="Detail.aspx?node=mine" />
</siteMapNode>
```

But it breaks if you try to go to "Detail.aspx?node=all&id=13" (Which I'm still trying solve.)

Answer (score 0):

One simple but effective way is to differentiate by using a different query string:

- default.aspx?page=1
- default.aspx?page=2
- default.aspx?page=3

They're all different in a sitemap, though they all point to the same page.